# Multiple ifs to action map

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the following example code with multiple ifs to one using an action map but I don't have any idea on how to do that efficiently with the modulo operator.

```
if ((playerChoice + 1) % 3 === computerChoice) {
    return 0;
}
if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 1;
}
return 2;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the problem with your code (it seems to be OK)? What do you want to do with it? What's an action map you're talking about? It's a bit unclear to me. Please elaborate a bit more on the problem

Comment: It's for a project at university and the prof dislikes multiple ifs (and switches and the ternary operator).  The modified version of ESLint which we have to use tells us to "Use action map instead of if - if" . I guess an action map is the normal array map method but I am not sure. The prof isn't of any help and tells us to solve the problem by ourselves.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't see a way to make this code clearer (you could use ternaries, but they wouldn't be much more readable here, IMHO). I can't see any problem with this code and can't think of any good (readable, clear) alternatives for this. I've never heard the term *action map* before (and even Googling didn't help), you could try to look up the documentation of the ESLint plugin you're using to get some directions on what problem does it have with your code, but I don't think I can help much more. Multiple ifs are really not good *in some cases*, but I don't think this is a such case.

Comment: Yeah I also searched for action maps but it didn't help. I didn't think to look up the documentation of the ESLint Plugin so thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
if ((playerChoice + 1) % 3 === computerChoice) {
    return 0;
} else if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 2;
}
```

It uses 1 if statement instead of 2, which does follow your request. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: actually your code and OP's code are the same. OP's code is using a more syntetic way of representing the if else